# How to add Bugs to TFS 2012 task board

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to follow the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh739066(v=vs.110).aspx for "Work item types that appear on the task board page".  I add `<WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />` to the Task Category.  However, when I import the categories I get an error message saying `TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature.`  Does anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong?  That is the only configuration that I have changed.  If I remove the new line from the config and re-import it, everything works fine.

It's worth noting that I'm using the Scrum 2.0 process template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the required fields to the bug work item type?  You may want to download the scrum template to your machine and checkout the following file  "workitem tracking\process\commonConfiguration.xml"

It suggests you need the following states for items in the task category

- To Do
- In Progress
- Complete

You may also need the fields defined

- remainingwork
- activity
- effort

Comment: As soon as I change the workflow to include those states and add the fields I get the error on the task board.  At this point I haven't even tried adding bug to the task category.

Comment: In addition to doing what you suggested, I also needed to modify CommonConfiguration BugCategory.

Comment: @devlife did you end up with a bunch of extra columns on the board, or did you merge them somehow?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey I can't remember off the top of my head what I ended up doing.  I think I needed to add a work item type to the bug category.

Comment: @Betty There weren't any extra columns that I recall.

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution to this problem [on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFSvnext/thread/dc6103da-4b6d-4504-bf39-9a110b731c62/).  I was using the Agile 6.1 process template though, not scrum 2.0.  Essentially I just had to add the RemainingWork and Activity fields to my Bug work item type (in addition to adding the Bug work item type to the Task Category in the Categories.xml).

Comment: I only had to add the Bug work item type to the Task Category in categories.xml AND make sure my States matched the possible Bug States in Common Process Config file.  I did not have to add the RemainingWork or Activity fields to my bug WorkItemType.